# php -l returns no errors

Tags: php, atom-editor

I recently started using the Atom editor. I installed the linter-php package both on my laptop and my work desktop. On my work computer, when there's an error, it works as expected, however, on my laptop, nothing. I noticed the command says it works via `php -l` which I assume is PHP's own built in linting (I can't find anything online about it). When I make a very obvious error (like not putting in a semicolon) and run `php -l` via a command line, PHP says there's nothing wrong with the file.

So is there something wrong with my PHP install? Or am I not understanding how PHP's linting is supposed to work?

Comment: [PHP Command Line Options](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) And linting should identify syntax errors in the file you're checking.... if it doesn't, then either your'e not lint checking the file that you believe you are (likely); or you've got a major snafu in your PHP Install (highly unlikely)

Comment: That was my first thought too, but I double checked the file more than once, and as mentioned, I was using the linter through an Atom plugin that works on another computer. I also felt it stupidly unlikely that the install messed up somehow, but based on your response and my general proclivity to luck, I'm guessing maybe PhP is somehow screwed up...